# Properly redirect to a view controller inside tab bar's navigation controller when push notification is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `tabBar`. Each of its tabs' `ViewControllers` have been embedded inside their respective `NavigationControllers`.

Hierarchy:

`Tabbarcontroller` --> `NavigationController` --> VC1 --> VC2 -->...VCn (for tab1)

I have to redirect to one of the viewcontrollers say VC2 when i click on push notifications. The code i am using is as follows.

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController()
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
if let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatViewController") as? ChatViewController {
    navigationController.viewControllers = [chatViewController]
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
}
```

By using this, I am redirected to the respective `ViewController`. However, i am not able to get back to the `tabBar`. So is it possible to redirect in such a way that it allows me the get back to the tab bar, thus providing the same hierarchy as in the UI?

EDIT:

The image below shows my layout.

[image]

I would like to accomplish the following:

1. When the user taps the push notification, the app should be directed to VC-B. *It should not create new object for VC-B and add to the navigation stack if VC-B is already on top of navigation stack.
2. If the app had been terminated and the user taps on the notification, it should open VC-B.

For determining if the app had been terminated, I set a flag as:

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: UserDefaultsKey.isTerminated)
}
```

This flag is set false at the end of didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function.

For redirection, I check this flag to determine if the app had been terminated:

```
func performRedirectionToSuitableViewController(userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
  
    let isTerminated = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: UserDefaultsKey.isTerminated) as! Bool
    
    if isTerminated {
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
        
        let tab = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as! UITabBarController
        
        tab.selectedIndex = 0
        
        let nav = tab.viewControllers![0] as! UINavigationController
        
        let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatViewController") as! ChatViewController
        
        chatViewController.chatThreadId = userInfo["thread_id"] as? String
        
        nav.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: true)

    } else {

        if let tab = window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? UITabBarController {

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)

            let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatViewController") as! ChatViewController
                
            chatViewController.chatThreadId = userInfo["thread_id"] as? String
               
            if let nav = tab.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
                   
                nav.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: true)
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

With this code, my first requirement is partially fulfilled. Need to determine if the viewcontroller is at the top of the navigation stack.

And, in the case of terminated app, clicking the push notification opens the tab bar, with the default selection index being selected.

I have spent several days trying to fix this. But cannot get it work.

Comment: why are you setting rootview controller why not simple push

Comment: when you get into the app from the push notification, there is a possibility, you are not in the place where you wanna be, so the push is not always a suitable option

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have to do something like this:

```
let tabBar: UITabBarController // get your tab bar
tabBar.selectedIndex = 0 // eg. zero. To be sure that you are on correct tab
if let navigation = tabBar.viewControllers?[tabBar.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    if let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatViewController") as? ChatViewController {
        navigation.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

Comment: did not open the desired viewcontroller with this code.

Comment: @Sujal So, you have `UITabBarController` which has several tabs. Each tab has `UINavigationController` as a root. You would like to open `ChatViewController` on a specific tab (eg. tab index 1 ). Right? If so, 1) switch your tab bar to the right tab `tabBar.selectedIndex = 0`; 2) get navigationController on the current tab (like I did); 3) create new instance of  `ChatViewController` and push it to the navigationController. You can set a breakpoint on this code and check if all of this object exists.

Comment: All the conditions are passed, however, the viewcontroller that has been pushed does not show up. It just opens the tab the app was left before. 
P.S. I have few more view controllers before the tabBarController (for login). This should not make a difference, right?

Comment: Right. If you an explicit access to tabBarController (which is on the screen in a moment when app become active) it should work. It works for me. You may have some other reason why it's not working.

Comment: @AndrewBogaevskyi - this was a life saver a couple of years later - worked perfectly!

Comment: Though when on a device, it actually seems that there isn't enough time between tabBar.selectedIndex = 0 and the rest of the code executing, so I can end up with an incorrect stack.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are setting current `window.rootViewController`, which should be that `TabBarViewController` I'd say. That's why you cannot get back to the `TabBar`

## What you should do is

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
if let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatViewController") as? ChatViewController, let tabBar = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBar") as? UITabBarController {
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: chatViewController)
    navigationController.viewControllers = [chatViewController]
    tabBar.viewControllers = [navigationController]
    window?.rootViewController = tabBar
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current navigation controller from the tabbar controller. You can use this function

```html
func getVisibleViewController(_ rootViewController: UIViewController?) -> UIViewController? {
        
        var rootVC = rootViewController
        if rootVC == nil {
            rootVC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
        }
        
        if rootVC?.presentedViewController == nil {
            return rootVC
        }
        
        if let presented = rootVC?.presentedViewController {
            if presented.isKind(of: UINavigationController.self) {
                let navigationController = presented as! UINavigationController
                return navigationController.viewControllers.last!
            }
            
            if presented.isKind(of: UITabBarController.self) {
                let tabBarController = presented as! UITabBarController
                return tabBarController.selectedViewController!
            }
            
            //UIAlertController
            if presented.isKind(of: UIAlertController.self) {
                let alertController = presented as! UIAlertController
                return alertController.presentingViewController
            }
            return getVisibleViewController(presented)
        }
        return nil
    }
```

Using the function you can navigate your viewcontroller like below.

```html
let mainStoryboardIpad : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let yourView = mainStoryboardIpad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "yourView") as! NewnoteViewController

                let navi = self.getVisibleViewController(self.window!.rootViewController) as! UINavigationController
               
                navi.pushViewController(yourView, animated: true)
```

Comment: The codes seem working, however I have two concerns.
1. If the app is terminated and later the notification is clicked, the app does not open the desired VC
2. When the user is in the same VC and the push notification is clicked, I would like to stay in the same VC rather than create a new one in the stack
How can I fix these, especially the first one?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a method in your RootViewController that will redirect user to a specific view after receiving a push notification. Here's what I did in my previous project.

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    private var currentView: UIViewController
    
    init() {
        self.currentView = ViewController()
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addChildViewController(currentView)               // 1
        currentView.view.frame = view.bounds              // 2
        view.addSubview(currentView.view)                 // 3
        currentView.didMove(toParentViewController: self) // 4
    }
    
    func showDetailsScreen() {
        if let updateDetailView = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UpdateDetailsNotif") as? UpdateDetailsViewController{
            
            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: updateDetailView)

            addChildViewController(navController)
            navController.view.frame = view.bounds
            view.addSubview(navController.view)
            navController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
            currentView.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
            currentView.view.removeFromSuperview()
            currentView.removeFromParentViewController()
            currentView = navController
        }
        
    }
   
}
```

Then you can call that method on your AppDelegate like this:

```
  func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let application = UIApplication.shared
  
        AppDelegate.shared.rootViewController.showDetailsScreen()
       
        completionHandler()
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        print("didReceive2: ", userInfo)
        Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)
        
            //        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NotificationName.openRaceDAyTipsTab, object: nil)
        
        let application = UIApplication.shared
        
        if(application.applicationState == .active) {
            print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in foreground")
        }
        
        if(application.applicationState == .inactive) {
            print("user tapped the notification bar when the app is in background")
        }
        
        guard let rootViewController = (UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first?.delegate as? SceneDelegate)?.window?.rootViewController else {
            return
        }
        print("got active scene")
        
        
            // handle the push notification here
        if let articleId = userInfo["articleId"] as? String {
                // use the articleId in your app logic
                // Create an instance of ArticlesDetailViewController
            let articlesDetailVC = ArticlesDetailViewController.instantiateHome()
            articlesDetailVC.articlesId = articleId
            
            if let tabBarVC = rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
               let navVC = tabBarVC.selectedViewController as? UINavigationController {
                navVC.pushViewController(articlesDetailVC, animated: true)
            }
        }
        
        completionHandler()
    }
```