# Navigate to child VC of a tab bar and set search bar data

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app that has 4 tab bar items (A, B, C, D).  I'm using notification data to direct a user to a child vc of A ('A-child') and I want to populate the search bar in A-child with a value from the notification.

I'm successfully getting the notification and value, that's fine.  I'm also able to navigate to A just fine using:

```
let tabBarController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
```

But I then need to navigate to A-Child VC from A and then set the search bar text (I'm less worried about the search bar text piece as I think I can work that out once I get the right VC stack in place).  I could of course use a segue to go straight from where the user when they tap on the notification to A-child, but then I lose the expected navigation behaviour for the user from A-child.

I know I'm not the first to ask a question like this, and I've gone through everything I can find on SO relating to this - but can't make any of the answers click.  Help is much appreciated!

Edit:

I've got it partially working with this:

```
if let tabbarController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? 
    UITabBarController {
    let vc = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AChildViewController") as! 
    AChildViewController
    vc.searchString = "text"
    tabarController.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

1. Not sure if this is an appropriate way or I'm going to get myself in trouble
2. It isn't being presented inside the navigation controller - so I'm not getting the top nav bar (including the critical search bar)
3. It isn't being presented inside the tab bar controller

when I tried to do tabBarController.navigationController? < the navigation controller is nil

> EDIT 2 - Solution:

Found an unaccepted answer from a couple of years ago that did the trick for me via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51763243/12481584

```
let tabBar: UITabBarController // get your tab bar
tabBar.selectedIndex = 0 // eg. zero. To be sure that you are on correct tab
if let navigation = tabBar.viewControllers?[tabBar.selectedIndex] as? UINavigationController {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    if let chatViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "chatViewController") as? ChatViewController {
        navigation.pushViewController(chatViewController, animated: true)
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not so clear, but I assume your problem is basically how to navigate to a child controller of `TAB A` from anywhere.

There are multiple ways to do this (`deep-linking`), but the most straight forward way literally just do your usual approach of pushing, popping, presenting, dismissing of controllers and combine local storage of your data that indicates where you should redirect the user to after tapping a push notification or deep-linking from anywhere such as a website.

An extension of getting the current or top most screen should help, for instance, the is how I do it:

```
import UIKit

var windowRootController: UIViewController? {
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        let windowScene = UIApplication.shared
            .connectedScenes
            .filter { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
            .first
        
        if let window = windowScene as? UIWindowScene {
            return window.windows.last?.rootViewController
        }
        
        return UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.rootViewController
    } else {
        return UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
    }
}

/// Category for any controller.
extension UIViewController {
    /// Class function to get the current or top most screen.
    class func current(controller: UIViewController? = windowRootController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let controller = controller else { return nil }
        
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return current(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return current(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller.presentedViewController {
            return current(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }
}
```

---

Now, onto your specific problem. So assuming you really now handle the redirection to `TAB A` properly, the next thing you would do is push the `Child A` after going to the `TAB A`, and then in the `Child A` didAppear, put the text in the searchBar and do the searching.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do - get to a child VC of tab A.  in effect are you suggesting that I get to A (which I'm doing fine today) and then within A, have something that checks  to see if I'm coming in via a deep link, and if so, then push the child VC onto the stack?  OR is there a way to more elegantly handle this when I'm evaluating the deep link and not have a check within A?

Comment: and I'm probably missing something obvious - but can you elaborate on the use case for the code you shared?

Comment: There are "more elegant" way to do deep-linking, for instance, by using ```Router``` or ```Coordinator```. But of course, these are merely layers to separate the screen navigation of your project. Like I said in my answer, one way to do the "checking" if you're coming in via a deep-link from a website or a push notification and whatnot, is have a singleton variable or static variable or defaults that stores the task you wanna do when you reach a certain screen (say TAB A), & from there, do what you have to do. About the sample code I posted, it's just for getting the "current"/topmost screen.

Comment: Got it - I think I'm nearly there - have a look at my edit if you have a chance, the last piece seems to be that I need to add the navigation controller into the stack